# R: how to apply to a list a function that loops over the previous subelements

Tags: r, list, function, apply

I guess this is better understood with an example, I feel this is really easy but I cannot get around it...

I have a list that looks like this:

> [[1]] [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
>
> [[2]] [1] "A" "B" "C"
>
> [[3]] [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
>
> [[4]] [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
>
> [[5]] [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

And I want to obtain this:

> [[1]] [1] "A" "A;B" "A;B;C" "A;B;C;D" "A;B;C;D;E" "A;B;C;D;E;F"
>
> [[2]] [1] "A" "A;B" "A;B;C"
>
> [[3]] [1] "A" "A;B" "A;B;C" "A;B;C;D"
>
> [[4]] [1] "A" "A;B" "A;B;C" "A;B;C;D"
>
> [[5]] [1] "A" "A;B" "A;B;C" "A;B;C;D" "A;B;C;D;E"

So I need a function to apply in this way:

```
list2 <- lapply(list1,
                function(x) {
                  #something here
                })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop through the `list`, get the sequence of the length of elements, loop through it with `sapply`, extract the `list` elements based on the index and `paste`

```
lapply(list1, function(x) sapply(seq(length(x)),
     function(i) paste(x[seq_len(i)], collapse=",")))
#[[1]]
#[1] "A"           "A,B"         "A,B,C"       "A,B,C,D"     "A,B,C,D,E"   "A,B,C,D,E,F"

#[[2]]
#[1] "A"     "A,B"   "A,B,C"

#[[3]]
#[1] "A"       "A,B"     "A,B,C"   "A,B,C,D"

#[[4]]
#[1] "A"       "A,B"     "A,B,C"   "A,B,C,D"

#[[5]]
#[1] "A"         "A,B"       "A,B,C"     "A,B,C,D"   "A,B,C,D,E"
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`

```
lapply(list1, function(x) Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep=","), x, accumulate = TRUE))
```

This can be written without an anonymous function call if the `sep` is not important

```
lapply(list1, Reduce, f = paste, accumulate = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
list1 <- lapply(c(6, 3, 4, 4, 5), function(i) LETTERS[1:i])
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!